# Intellij 11.1.5 - Project specific path variable

Tags: intellij-idea, path-variables, system-variable

I am using the Intellij 11.1.5. We are a large team, and have a pretty complex project setup. so we've made a template and when someone needs a new project set up, we just clone it and she is pretty much ready to go. One other thing i would like to automate is the creation of run configurations. One such configuration starts a custom bat file that requires a parameter representing a path that is user specific. I wanted to know if can store that value as a path variable specific to each project. Maybe somewhere in the .idea folder in my project. I know that Intellij stores it in its .IntelliJIdea11\config\options\path.macros.xml file, but is there a way to tweak that?

Any other idea that would allow me to locally store a parameter passed to the run config script would be usefull.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do it in IDEA, but you can use some environment variable directly in the `.bat` file instead of using the parameter (or rewrite the batch script to detect this value automatically, if possible). Instruct your users to define this environment variable.

IDEA Path variables are global and cannot be made project specific.